# select posts from one day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to select posts from one day. What is the correct way? This errors:

```
date = '3/11/2016'.to_date

User.joins(:posts).where(posts: {'created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day})
```

Comment: What error does this give?

Comment: unexpected `}`, syntax in general

Comment: `User.joins(:posts).where('posts.created_at >= ? AND posts.created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Posts.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today)
```

There is no need to join User unless you want the user as well then you could do this

```
User.joins(:posts).all.where('posts.created_at >= ? and posts.created_at <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today).preload(:posts)
```

The `preload` will help with efficiency

Comment: Is `preload` kind of like `include`?

Comment: Also +1 for thinking about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to select by day you might try something like this.

`User.joins(:posts).where(posts: { 'extract(day from created_at) = ?', desired_day_of_month } )`

Comment: Maybe something along these lines then `'2016-11-03'.to_date.day`

Answer (score 0):

you have an issue with the syntax:

```
posts: {'created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day}
```

the hash syntax should be used to send the columns to query, such as:

```
posts: { title: 'some title' }, etc
```

In your case, you should do:

```
User.joins(:posts).where('posts.created_at >= ? AND posts.created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day)
```